# How to Enable and Disable time in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to enable the time when click on the enable button and disable the time when click on the disable button...
**HTML**

```
 <p id="demo"></p> 
 <select>
    <option onselect="enable()">Enable</option>
    <option onselect="disable()"> disable</option>
 </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}


function enable() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "block";

}

function disable() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "none";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Basit, welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review [ask].  This post doesn't ask a clear question, so it it not clear what you are looking for.  Review tips on asking a good question and come back and update/edit your post.  Once you have a clear, concise question the community is much more likely to provide you with useful feedback.  Good luck!

Comment: Did you mean like stopwatch?

Answer (score 2):

in your `disable` function clear the inetrval

```
function disable() {
   clearInterval(myVar);
   document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none"; // set style not HTML
}
```

to enable time again modify your `enable` method as:

```
function enable() {
   document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
   myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the *style* to change an element's style, not its `innerHTML`.

```js
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  demo.textContent = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  demo.style.display = "block";
  else demo.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<select>
    <option value="Enable">Enable</option>
    <option value="Disable">Disable</option>
 </select>
```

Also, when inserting text (not HTML markup), make sure to use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML` - it's faster and safer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use th `onchange` event of the `select` (because as far as I know there is no `onselect` event) and check the value selected. Then if it is `Disable`, clear the interval with `clearInterval`, else start it again:

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}

function toggle(select) {
  let demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (select.value === 'Disable') {
     clearInterval(myVar);
     demo.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    demo.style.display = 'block';
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p> 
<select onchange="toggle(this)">
  <option>Enable</option>
  <option>Disable</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to completely hide when select the disable and show when select the enable @kirill simonov

Comment: @Basit then, as suggested by others, you need to change the style of the `demo` element. Check my update.

Answer (score 1):

There you go, following are the corrections made

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}

function enable() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block"; //changed `innerHTML` with `style.display`
}

function disable() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none"; //changed `innerHTML` with `style.display`
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<select onchange='window[this.value]()'> <!-- added onchange -->
    <option value='enable'>Enable</option> <!--  added `value` removed `onselect` -->
    <option value='disable'>Disable</option> <!-- same as above -->
 </select>
```

In above code, this line `window[this.value]()` will invoke functions i.e. `enable` or `disable` as per the option selected.

Comment: Very very thanks @Arvind...yes that is mistake therefore not hide and display....